# How to define an adapter trait where some implementations need a lifetime on &self?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm writing a set of benchmarks for different key-value stores, and would like to have a single adapter trait that I can use in all the benchmarks, and then implement it for each key-value store.

This worked well for two of them. However, the third required me to add a lifetime on my trait, and after fighting the borrow checker for an entire day, I still can't seem to get it right.

I've distilled it down to this minimal repro: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54fec74cb70c63c03f25ec7a9dfc7e60

What I don't understand is why the borrow on `txn` lives longer than the scope of `benchmark()`. It seems to me that it should live for only that one line.

How can I define the `AdapterTransaction` trait to resolve this, that still allows implementations to choose their own return type?

*edit*

added that I need to be able to use the `AdapterTransaction` implementations with a factory trait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your [first playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a98b9678aa0ccc3ac974b4327c7c3a4) is the lifetime on `&self` being the same as the generic lifetime on the trait.

```rust
pub trait AdapterTransaction<'a, T: AsRef<[u8]>> {
    fn get(&'a self, key: &[u8]) -> Option<T>;
}
```

Because they are the same, it requires the borrow of the underlying type to live at least as long as the type itself. This isn't true because even though the type is owned, the borrow would only last for the duration of the function call. In `benchmark<'a,...>()`, the lifetime `'a` is picked by the caller, and there is no way a borrow within that function can be long enough. There would have been a quick fix to remove the `'a` parameter on `benchmark` and replace it with a higher ranked trait bound ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e21696c69502c2c188fbc98712d75b01)).

```rust
fn benchmark<U: AsRef<[u8]>, T: for<'a> AdapterTransaction<'a, U>>(txn: T)
```

In this example, `'a` isn't chosen by the caller anymore, so the compiler is free to use a valid lifetime for the call.

As for the 2nd part of your question, traits can define associated types which can change depending on the implementation. You could have a trait that has an associated `Output`, which can change for each implemented type. There is a big difference with doing a generic param vs an associated type since in the former case, you are allowed to implement multiple generic variants of a trait for the same type. (This is how `From<T>` works, for example).

```rust
pub trait AdapterTransaction<'a> {
    type Output;

    fn get(&'a self, key: &[u8]) -> Option<Self::Output>;
}

impl<'a> AdapterTransaction<'a> for AdapterImpl {
    type Output = &'a [u8];
    
    fn get(&'a self, key: &[u8]) -> Option<Self::Output> {
        Some(self.txn.get(&key))
    }
}

fn benchmark<T>(txn: T)
 where
    for<'a> T: AdapterTransaction<'a>,
{
    let _ = txn.get(&[]).unwrap();
}
```

**Edit:** Some of my initial assumptions weren't exact, it's not necessary to implement on &'a Type if the trait lifetime is used in a non-conflicting way.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion! Ya, I tried this approach, but I haven't been able to make it work. The reason is that I need a factory that can create these transaction objects, which I think means the type needs to implement the trait and not just a reference. I added a minimal version of the factory to your playground link here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54fec74cb70c63c03f25ec7a9dfc7e60

Comment: Does this capture your requirements? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8506c95bea696db5a1750c45d3936e41

Comment: Yes, it seems to! I never thought of doing the implementation of the factory on a reference too. I'll try it out in my actual code, and see if I encounter more issues

Comment: Ah, so unfortunately this doesn't work in my actual code. Applying the &'a trick to the TableImpl doesn't work, because then it can't return the constructed objects. See here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28016870f2d68e4552e91ad169c90ed1

Comment: You can move the bounds from the associated type to the benchmark function (where the syntax is a bit more flexible) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbe31c122b93aebd1f62ee3b4f57d754

Comment: I realized, with the bounds out of the way, it's not even necessary to implement it on a reference anymore :D https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2cc41e9ae1a18513ade513bc743e4717